# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Laravel 8 livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want close modal after save data

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModel');

<script>
    window.addEventListener('closeModel', event => {
        $("#Add_Student_Model").modal('hide');
    })
</script>
```

But error:

> `Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined`

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` by any chance? If so it is likely because your function is being defined before `jQuery` has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should type your code inside function block.

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModel');

        window.addEventListener('closeModel', event => {
            $("#Add_Student_Model").modal('hide');
        })
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```